# How to pass Excel data through Csv file inside a Loop Controller in Jmeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

In my script i have a loop controller before a bunch of requests,and i have parameterized the request data for eg. in my case it is the row number I parameterized. I added a CSV file before the thread group too.Issue is it is only taking the first row of variables in excel file.I understand the sharing options are All Threads,Current Thread,Current Thread Group so it will take next row values in the next iteration.How to make the Csv file work in a loop controller to pass next row values? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

CSV Data Set Config should be under Loop Controller (which is under Thread Group).

That how each line will be taken for each loop iteration.

```
-Thread Group
...
   -Loop Controller

       - CSV Data Set Config
```

Comment: CSV Data Set Config should be under Loop Controller (which is under Thread Group) - updated answer

Comment: In Thread Group there is a Loop Count field i want to keep it as 1 but need to run 2 iterations in Loop controller,so if i add csv under loop controller will it take each line for each iteration ? (P.S:Read that the csv takes the next line only if loop count in thead group is >1 not for controller).is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean the iteration due to loop controller or the loop count in thread group?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJhDQ.png)